# structuring web-service response to readable format

Tags: json, web-services, post, python-requests

I´m using requests to get the pricing data populating:

http://brochurer.ford.dk/Prisliste/Finansiering/FordPrivatleasing/

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://brochurer.ford.dk/Prisliste/Finansiering/FordPrivatleasing/'
payload = {
"Host": "brochurer.ford.dk",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Length": 83,
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Referer": "http://brochurer.ford.dk/Prisliste/Finansiering/FordPrivatleasing/",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
"Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5",
"Cookie": "mbox=session#3137d01ef37340f38391b36e6f86f25e#1484037013|PC#3137d01ef37340f38391b36e6f86f25e.26_18#1486454353|check#true#1484035213; s_cc=true; s_fid=13CC8A6D6DD1311C-3A779E9585A86012; s_p_s_prop8=search-natural; s_sq=fmeudkprod%2Cfmeuprod%3D%2526pid%253Dcredit%25253Afinance%25253Aleasing%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fbrochurer.ford.dk%25252FPrisliste%25252FFinansiering%25252FFordPrivatleasing%25252F%2526ot%253DA; ASP.NET_SessionId=elfrb32c2ho0mlqvmj51mv1n; s_suite=nosuitefmeudkprod%2Cfmeuprod; v_starting=nfp",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache"}

headers = {}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r.encoding)
```

But the data is pretty useless. All the data I want is in one single paragraph:

```
<p>Ford Privatleasing 05-01-2017 Ka+ Model 5 dørs Ultimate 1.2** **Årlig kørsel 10.000 km Fiesta Model 5 dørs Titanium 1.0 EccoBoost** **Årlig kørsel 10.000 km Focus Model Stationcar Trend 1.0 EcoBoost Business 1.0 EcoBoost Vinter Edition inkl. vinterhjul Business 1.0 EcoBoost Vinter Edition ekskl. vinterhjul Mondeo Model 5 dørs Titanium 1.5 EcoBoost*** Titanium 1.5 EcoBoost*** Stationcar Titanium 1.5 EcoBoost*** Titanium 1.5 EcoBoost*** ***Inkl. Businesspakke 1 S-MAX Model MPV Titanium 1.5 EcoBoost Titanium 2.0 EcoBoost Gear HK Km/l CO2 g/km Energiklasse Afgift* Engangsydelse 5 85 20,8 110 grøn 310 4.995 Mdl. leasingydelse 1.895 Totalomk. 73.215 Gear HK Km/l CO2 g/km Energiklasse Afgift* Engangsydelse 5 125 23,3 99 grøn 310 4.995 Mdl. leasingydelse 1.995 Totalomk. 76.815 Gear HK Km/l CO2 g/km Energiklasse Afgift* Engangsydelse 5 100 20,8 109 6 125 20,8 110 6 125 20,8 110 grøn 310 grøn 310 grøn 310 0 6.995 6.995 Mdl. leasingydelse 2.995 3.195 2.995 Totalomk. 107.820 122.015 114.815 Gear HK Km/l CO2 g/km Energiklasse Afgift* Engangsydelse 6 160 17,2 134 A6 160 15,9 146 orange 890 orange 1.190 24.995 24.995 Mdl. leasingydelse 4.295 4.495 Totalomk. 179.615 186.815 6 160 16,9 137 A6 160 15,4 152 orange 890 orange 1.190 24.995 24.995 4.395 4.595 183.215 190.415 Gear HK Km/l CO2 g/km Energiklasse Afgift* Engangsydelse 6 160 15,4 149 A6 240 12,7 180 1.190 2.060 24.995 29.995 Mdl. leasingydelse 4.495 5.345 Totalomk. 186.815 222.415 *Grøn ejerafgift pr. ½ år. Leasingydelserne er baseret på 36 mdr. og 15.000 km/året, med mindre andet er angivet. De er inkl. serviceaftale, finansierings- og leveringsomkostninger. Ekskl. dæk, grøn ejerafgift, forsikring og brændstof. Positiv kreditgodkendelse forudsættes. Tilbuddene er gældende til og med 31/3 2017, gælder kun nye biler bestilt fra fabrikken, og kan ikke kombineres med øvrige tilbud. Ved leasingperiodens udløb returneres bilen til Ford Privatleasing. Der tages forbehold for pris- og afgiftsændringer samt trykfejl. Kaskoforsikring og betaling via NETS er påkrævet.</p>
```

Am I encoding wrong?
Is there any way to structure the data to some readable json?

Answer (score 0):

Frank, can you add what is being returned?  Jim

Comment: I´m getting hundreds of lines returned - it´s unfortunately too difficult to put them in a post. Perhaps you can run the above code? But the only part I´m interested in is the above posted paragraph:

Comment: Frank, it is returning the entire webpage contents in HTML format, not JSON.  Plus, the data you are looking to extract doesn't have an 'id' that you could then pull directly, by passing it to a DOM processor.  Your best bet would be to manually parse that entire string on the first <p> up to the first </p>.  That said, if they change their webpage format, you'll have to adjust what you're doing.  HTH, Jim

Comment: thanks for the response - I agree theres no key to identify values by. I was hoping there was some way to see the response data before the document is populated. Isn´t there some way to mimic the request and retrieve the data?

Comment: You are retrieving the data - it is serving up the HTML page as one big text string.  To see anything else, the website would have to have some other mechanism to request data since the JSON call didn't really work, like an API.  It would help if they had given your text an 'id=', but you would still run into the issue that they could change their webpage whenever they want.  HTH, Jim